# Formally describe a similarity function

Tags: functions, formal-languages

I have a function that takes two real world objects as input and returns a real value between 0 and 1 as the similarity of the two objects. How to formally describe this function in mathematical language? I am looking for something like $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Wait, so is the input a 'real world object' or a real number?

Comment: Your question is *far* too vague and under-specified.  Does color affect similarity?  Mass?  Material?  Shape (and if so, how to quantify similarity)?

Comment: If your function takes two "real world objects" then and you refer to that domain as $\mathbb{RWO}$ then $f: \mathbb{RWO}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Comment: I have my own method to compute similarity, I want to describe the function in a formal way in terms of its input and output. The input is real world object or entity, for example, weather of a place. The output is a real value between 0 and 1, and I write it as $f: \mathbb{O}^2 \rightarrow [0,1]$?

Answer (score 2):

Encode the two objects into feature vectors of length $n$, call them $x$ and $y$.

Suppose you have two vectors, $x, y$ where they are componentwise nonnegative.

One possible approach to use Jaccard similarity coefficient.

$$J(x,y)=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \min(x_i, y_i)}{\sum_{i=1}^n \max{x_i, y_i}}$$

For the case of binary vectors.

Let $M_{11}$ represents the total number of attributes where $x$ and $y$ both have a value of $1$.

Let $M_{01}$ represents the total number of attributes where the attribute of $x$ is $0$ and the attribute of $y$ is $1$.

Let $M_{10}$ represents the total number of attributes where the attribute of $x$ is $1$ and the attribute of $y$ is $0$.

$$J(x,y)=\frac{M_{11}}{M_{10}+M_{01}+M_{11}}$$

You can read more about Jaccard similarity [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index)

Comment: If you have non-binary attributes you want to compare, you could use the "generalized Jaccard similarity and distance"? Or "Tanimoto similarity and distance"?